# wpdb get results doesn't work with variable

Tags: wp-query

this is my code:

```
$search_by_input= $_POST["search_by_input"];
$client_id_by_nick_name = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT user_id FROM '. $user_meta_table .' WHERE meta_value ='.$search_by_input, ARRAY_A);
```

it doesn't work. but when I write the value instead of variable it works:

```
$client_id_by_nick_name = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT user_id FROM '. $user_meta_table .' WHERE meta_value ="admin"', ARRAY_A);
```

when I use `var_dump` for `$search_by_input` it shows this:

```
string 'admin' (length=5)
```

The only difference between that two lines is double quotation(before and after `admin` in second code.).

So Please tell me how can I fix this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Just an aside, but `$_POST["search_by_input"]` should be sanitized before being used in the query.

Comment: Is it harmful for security if I don't sanitized it?

Comment: Yes, user input should never be trusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
$search_by_input= $_POST["search_by_input"];
$client_id_by_nick_name = $wpdb->get_results( sprintf( "SELECT user_id FROM `%s` WHERE meta_value = '%s';", $user_meta_table, $search_by_input ), ARRAY_A);
```